# Circle detection on craters by Hough OpenCV - Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, houghcircles

I am trying to detect the circles on some lunar craters images. Here are some examples:

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]

After binarization, closing operation and removing noise, I ended up with such results:

[image: Example 1 - effect]
[image: Example 2 - effect]
[image: Example 3 - effect]

I am now trying to fit the circles to the binarized images. I've decided to use OpenCV and `HoughCircles()` method. I've found a very simple [example](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html) on the official OpenCV website, so I've used it in my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('binarized_image.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #read the image
assert img is not None, "file could not be read, check with os.path.exists()" #check if file exists

img = cv.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
circles = cv.HoughCircles(img,cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=30,param2=15,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
cv.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I am constantly ending up with error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint'`

It's the effect of line with `circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))`. It basically means, that my code did not detect ANY circles in the image. I've tried to modify `param1` and `param2` in the `cv.HoughCircles` but none of the values seems to work. The results that I expect should be something like this:

[image: Example 1 detection]
[image: Example 2 detection]
[image: Example 3 detection]

How can I achieve this and detect the circles? How should I modify my code?

Comment: Your initial binarization loses too much information. I would improve that step first. Having to adjust parameters to Hough for each image means you’re doing something wrong *before* Hough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me on Mac OSX Ventura. Note that I have added a line for cv.imwrite() to save the result to disk to show you.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('binarized_image.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #read the image
assert img is not None, "file could not be read, check with os.path.exists()" #check if file exists

img = cv.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
circles = cv.HoughCircles(img,cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=30,param2=15,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
cv.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv.imwrite('detected_circle.jpg',cimg)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

**ADDITION**

Your other images need changes to detect the circles. You are currently not getting any circles, thus the error.

Change param2=15 to param2=7 and you can detect the smallest image.

I get:

[image]

For the larger image, change param2=15 to param2=13 and I get

[image]

Comment: Please, try with other two images, you will probably see the same error as I do.

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer.  You need to change param2 for each image

Comment: Thank you, it seems I've always modified both param1 and param2 and because of that I could not detect any crater.